# Show statement as a subquery in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there a way to use the output of a show statement in a query? I am trying to query the table size in order to use it in a calculation but am getting the error of "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:16 cannot recognize input near '(' 'show' 'tblproperties' in from source".

```
select * from ( show tblproperties yourTableName("rawDataSize") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery is also a query and the SHOW keyword is not part of the FROM section of the query syntax.

Refer to this --> [FromClauseParser.g](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/parse/FromClauseParser.g)

You can also check the first line of the error message in the FromClauseParser.g page.

Error:

```
hive> select * from (show tblproperties emp_tmp);
NoViableAltException(239@[150:5: ( ( Identifier LPAREN )=> partitionedTableFunction | tableSource | subQuerySource | virtualTableSource )])
.
.
.
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:15 cannot recognize input near '(' 'show' 'tblproperties' in from source
```

Comment: this doesn't really get at my question